# "Manifolds are not Gorenstein"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, gorenstein

I recently heard someone say that manifolds are not Gorenstein.
To me being Gorenstein means that the canonical divisor is Cartier. So I don't understand why manifolds aren't Gorenstein, since on a smooth variety all divisors are Cartier.

Comment: Why don't you ask `someone' that you heard what he/she meant?

Comment: @Mohan Because I'm not sure who said it; it was someone the audience of a talk I attended

Comment: Without more details, impossible to know what was meant. In projective geometry, there is a related concept of Arithmetically Gorenstein, which most manifolds are not.

Comment: In general I think questions of this form (which appear quite frequently here) are not suitable, because as Mohan says it's impossible to answer them without knowing the context.

Comment: @bertram I don't see why its impossible to answer them. Either manifolds are Gorenstein, or they are not. Its a yes or no question...

Comment: @user2520938: that is not true; it could also be meaningless. Gorenstein is a condition on a scheme, and manifolds are not schemes, so it doesn't obviously make sense to ask whether a manifold is Gorenstein, in the same way that it doesn't obviously make sense to ask whether a manifold is yellow.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Obviously I mean a smooth variety

Comment: That is not at all obvious, since you used the word "manifold" both in the title and in the body of the question. If you meant a smooth variety why didn't you just say that?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Because like you, I was confused by what was said, and wanted to  state it the way I heard it, so that someone could help me interpret it. When I heard the word manifold in relation to being Gorenstein, I assumed it should be interpreted as meaning a smooth variety

Comment: As Mohan says, it is not at all obvious that this is what was meant, especially since, as you say, if you interpret the statement that way it's not true. I googled "manifolds are not Gorenstein" and got this, which is not about smooth varieties: https://books.google.com/books?id=CUo-CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA112&lpg=PA112&dq=manifolds+are+not+gorenstein

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oke, I admit my question was too vague, because the notion mentioned in your book seems to be the correct one. It fits in with the context of the talk. Thanks

Comment: The local rings of a smooth variety are regular, and any regular ring is Gorenstein. The most obvious interpretation is out. More information on the quote is needed to address other possible interpretations. (Your approach via the canonical is also correct, since $\omega$ exists and is a line bundle for any smooth variety.)